# Concurrency while reading files from file system

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, filesystems, locking

We have an application that reads files from a particular folder, processes them and copies(some business logic) it to another folder.

The problem here is when there are very large number of files to be processed, running a single instance of an application  or a single thread is no longer enough to process this files.

**One approach we have for this is to start multiple instances of the application**(I feel something is wrong with this approach. Suggest me an alternative if there is one).

Spawning threads or starting multiple instances of the application, care should be taken that, if a thread reads one file and starts processing it, another thread should not pick it up.

We are trying to achieve this **by having a database table with the list of file names in the folder**, so that when a thread first reads the table for the file name ,we will change the status to ***in-process*** or ***completed*** and pessimistically lock the table so that other threads cannot read it.

Is there any better solution to the problem ?

Comment: You need to ensure the disk subsystem is not your bottle neck.  Running multiple processes or threads will help if CPU or an external service e.g. a database is your bottle neck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use most of your existing implementation as the front-end processor to feed file streams to worker threads that you can start/stop as demand dictates.  Only the front-end thread opens files, so there is **no** possibility of one worker interfering with another.

*EDIT: Added the word 'no' as it changes the meaning quite a bit...*

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at JDK 7. It has a new file I/O API and a fork/ join framework which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache Camel (http://camel.apache.org), and its File component (http://camel.apache.org/file2.html). Using Camel allows you to very easily define a set of processing instructions to consume files in a directory atomically, and also to configure a thread pool to deal with multiple files at the same time. Camel in Action's a great book to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe reminds me of the classical style to develop on UNIX.

In this classical style, you would move a file to a work-in-progress directory so that other files do not pick it up. In general: You could use one directory per processing state and than move files from state to state.

This works essentially because [file moves are atomic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) (at least under Unix systems and NFTS).

What is nice with this approach, is that it is pretty easy to handle problematic situations like crashes and it has automatically a nice management interface everyone is familiar with (the filesystem GUI, ls, Windows Explorer, ...).